# Error when add Handler

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6, orchardcms-1.7

I developed new module, when I add below code for handler and want to create one content from my new contentType in dashboard and submit form, I get an error. When I remove Handler or comment that the error was fixed but none part of data saved in database.

I checked, migration run OK and table created successfully. here is my model, record and part codes. Thanks...

```
// MyModulePart.cs
using System;
using Orchard.ContentManagement;

namespace www.MyModule.com.Models {
    public class MyModule : ContentPart<MyModuleRecord> {
        public string Name { get { return Record.Name; } set { Record.Name = value; } }
        public string ImdbRate { get { return Record.ImdbRate; } set { Record.ImdbRate = value; } } 
    }
}

// MyModulePartRecord.cs
using System;
using Orchard.ContentManagement.Records;

namespace www.MyModule.com.Models
{
    public class MyModulePartRecord : ContentPartRecord
    {
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string ImdbRate { get; set; }
    }
}

// Migration Code
SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("MyModulePartRecord", table => table
                                        .ContentPartRecord()
                                        .Column<string>("Name")
                                        .Column<string>("ImdbRate"));

// Handler Code
using Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers;
using Orchard.Data;
using www.MyModule.com.Models;

namespace www.MyModule.com.Handlers {
    public class MyModuleHandler : ContentHandler
    {
        public MyModuleHandler(IRepository<MyModulePartRecord> MyModulePartRepository)
        {
            Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(MyModulePartRepository));
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> null id in Orchard.ContentManagement.Records.ContentItemRecord entry
>   (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

please guide me.
Excuse me for my bad English.
Thanks...

Comment: I think the exception should contain more info in its inner exception. How does your part record look like? BTW record properties should be named in PascalCase.

Comment: I edit post and add model, record and part codes.

Comment: And what's in the inner exception?